# Definition of a dual Space

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is:

When the book says that a linear functional is a map from $V$ to $F$, is $F$ restricted to only the set of two elements 0 and 1?  If not, why can't $v_1$ map to say 8, in the first linear functional, $\varphi_1$.  The only restriction was that it maps from $V$ to $F$. However, obviously it can't because by definition of Dual Basis $\varphi_1(v_1)=1$. I just don't understand why.

Useful Notation and Definitions from book:

$F$ the field of real or complex numbers

A Linear Functional on $V$ is a linear map from $V$ to $F$.

Dual Space: The Dual Space, denoted V', is the vector space of all linear functionals on V.

Dual Basis: If $(v_1,....,v_n)$ is a basis of $V$, then the dual basis of $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is the list $(\varphi_1,....\varphi_n)$ of elements of $V'$, where each $\varphi_j$ is the linear functional on $V$ such that if k =  j, $\varphi_j(v_k) = 1$, otherwise $\varphi_j(v_k) = 0$.

Comment: $\phi_i$s just form a basis for $V'$.The point is that any linear functional can be written as a linear combination of the $\phi_i$s. For instance, $8\phi_1$ will map $v_1$ to $8$.

Comment: Exactly. The choice of zero and 1 is just that of convenience. You could just as well make it zero and two, but then the formulas would get cluttered with halfs and twos. I much prefer the ones and one over ones as they take less writing.

Comment: That makes sense, however, I am still a little confused on the point of a Dual Space/Basis.  They seems rigorously enough defined, but what is the purpose of them?